# Creating BSS files from CSS in JavaFX 9

Tags: java, css, javafx, java-9, javafx-9

I'm in the progress of upgrading my project to Java 9 due to Eclipse upgrade breaking APT in Java < 9 when working with Dagger 2.

I used to generate binary css files (bss) with the following command (which worked perfectly fine until Java 9):

```
$ javapackager -createbss -srcdir src/main/resources/view/ -outdir src/main/resources/view/
```

However after upgrading to Java 9 it errors out with:

> *Error: jfxrt.jar needs to be on classpath for -createbss and for -createJar without -nocss2bin*

Looking around I see that the `jfxrt.jar` is no longer present in my JDK 9 install. A google search finds [JavaFX 9 - New and Noteworthy - RainFocus[PDF]](https://static.rainfocus.com/oracle/oow16/sess/1462485593256001c2xn/ppt/JavaFX%209%20-%20New%20and%20Noteworthy.pdf) where it says:

> No more jfxrt.jar, it's baked into the JVM image

Has any one been able to generate bss files after upgrading to Java 9?

Comment: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8193353 is tracking the issue

Comment: @jewelsea this question was asked before the linked one.

Comment: Yes, but the other had an answer with an up-vote, so I could close it as a duplicate, but couldn't do that for this one.

Comment: @AlanBateman please post that as an answer.

Comment: @jewelsea sure. It just sucks because now it feels like I got the "fail at searching"-badge, and the question will be closed even though it was the only question at the time. :/